# Express.js Not Routing Properly after Passport.js Authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, passport.js

I have a fairly simple authentication setup using Passport.js. Once the user is authenticated, I have them redirect to /work, as so.

```
app.post('/login',
    passport.authenticate('local', {
        successRedirect: '/work',
        failureRedirect: '/login',
        failureFlash: true
    })
);
```

The entire authentication process works fine. Meaning, the program will refuse any incorrect user/password combo, etc. The real problem is when my program redirects to /work.

As shown above, the successRedirect should redirect it to /work. I have middleware to check if the user is logged in, like so:

```
function loggedIn(req, res, next) {
    console.log('call to login, ' + req.user);
    if (req.user) {
        console.log('calling next...');
        next();
    } else {
        console.log('redirecting...');
        res.redirect('/login');
    }
}
```

And my /work GET request looks like:

```
app.get('/work', loggedIn, function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('call to go to work')
    res.render("projects.html", {
        projects: getProjects()
    });
});
```

The problem is that rather than redirecting to /work after logging in, the browser just shows [object Object]. [object Object] is also logged to console. It doesn't even get to /work. If I remove loggedIn from the /work GET request, my page renders properly, which suggests to me that it's an issue in routing. Have I missed something obvious? Thank you so much in advance for any help you can give! :)

Logged to console during the process:

```
redirecting...
Authentication success!
[object Object]
```

Serialize and deserialize functions:

```
passport.serializeUser(function (user, cb) {
    cb(null, user.Email);
});
passport.deserializeUser(function (email, cb) {
    getInfo(email, function (user) {
        cb(user);
    });
});
```

Please note I never print [object Object] in any of my console.logs, so this seems to be a mystery.

Comment: So the url stays at `/login` and it just shows `[object Object]`? What prints on the console?

Comment: Sorry, let me reword -- it redirects to /login properly. I login properly, it works, but when redirecting to /work, I get a page that simply says [object Object]. Console in this scenario also logs [object Object], which is odd, since I have no console logs, either (I've checked)!

Comment: Have you tried custom callback as described in the last paragraph [here](http://passportjs.org/docs/authenticate)?

Comment: Yep, unfortunately. Same error :(

Comment: So, none of your logs in `loggedIn` is printed? Does the URL change to `/work`?

Comment: Yep. Right after I boot up the server, I go to /work -> here, loggedIn works and redirects me to /login. Once I login (and it checks properly if my login is correct), I am redirected to /work (the URL does change) and [object Object] is logged to console and rendered on the screen, but not my /work page. 'Call to go to work' is never called, which shows me that loggedIn seems to never finish here.

Comment: Might be an issue with your Passport deserializer.

Comment: Hmm, I'll post the serialize and deserialize functions above as well. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your deserializer doesn't look right:

```
passport.deserializeUser(function (email, cb) {
    getInfo(email, function (user) {
        cb(user);
    });
});
```

The common convention for Node callbacks is that the first argument is always used to pass errors. If there aren't any, the first argument should be falsy (generally, it's `null`).

I'm not sure is `getInfo` was implemented by yourself, but it also doesn't use the correct convention. I would strongly suggest to make it do so.

In any case, this is most likely the cause of your problem, because Passport thinks that you're passing it an error.

Once `getInfo` is fixed, you can rewrite the deserializer to this:

```
passport.deserializeUser(function (email, cb) {
    getInfo(email, cb);
});
```

Or even shorter:

```
passport.deserializeUser(getInfo);
```

Comment: Thanks! After a bit of modification, that fixed it. (It was due to the err handling!)